# Option Explicit does not see one undeclared variable, but works for other

Tags: excel, vba

For line with `Debug.Print` everything works fine, meaning `Option Explicit` catches an error and displays a pop-up about an undefined variable.

However, if I remove the `Debug.Print` line, which I added to see if `Option Explicit` works at all, code successfully executes. Compile is successful as well. It should not be, as there is a typo, "vDailBuys" instead of "vDailyBuys" in the 2nd `ReDim` statement.

Why isn't this typo detected?

I use the 2nd `ReDim` to clear array contents, nut sure if it is recommended way, but it works like a charm.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub test()

Dim vDailyBuys() As Variant

ReDim vDailyBuys(1, 10)
ReDim vDailBuys(1, UBound(vDailyBuys, 2)) As Variant
Debug.Print abcde

End Sub
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/redim-statement. "The ReDim statement acts as a declarative statement if the variable it declares doesn't exist at module level or procedure level."

Comment: Many thanks, this is very unexpected that I don't even need to `Dim` my variable if I `ReDim` it later. Such design kind of argues with the meaning of prefix "Re". You can put it as an answer.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement "When Option Explicit On or Option Explicit appears in a file, you must explicitly declare all variables by using the Dim or ReDim statements."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simply, with `Redim vDailBuys` you've declared a new variable `vDailBuys`, instead of your intended resizing of the original `vDailyBuys`.

From [MSDN - Redim Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/redim-statement): while "the ReDim statement is used to size or resize a dynamic array that has already been formally declared," it "acts as a declarative statement if the variable it declares **doesn't exist at module level or procedure level**." (emphasis mine).

Note that the same article advocates only using Redim to redimension arrays. Though it can be a declarative statement, as it is unintentionally in your case, it can cause conflicts that `Option Explicit` will not flag.